# how to search through firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to search through my firebase collection and get any document with the specific phonenumber entered, but it keeps returning nothing.

Here is a screensot of my database
[image]

Here is the code i used to query it:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .where("mobilenumber", isEqualTo: "+23407063435023")
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) { querySnapshot.docs.map((DocumentSnapShot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print("found");
      }
    });
}).catchError((error) => throw error);
```

and this is the security rule
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in then, I should have used `foreach` instead of a `map`,

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("users")
  .where("mobilenumber",isEqualTo: "+23409056088820")
  .get()
  .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print(documentSnapshot.id);
      }
  });
                                        
}).catchError((error) {
  print(error);
});
```

I don't know why though.

Answer (score 0):

Your query searches docs on `country`, not on `phonenumber`. Adapt it as follows:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("users")
    .where("phonenumber", isEqualTo: "12345")
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) { querySnapshot.docs.map((DocumentSnapShot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print("found");
      }
    });
}).catchError((error) => throw error);
```

Comment: i changed it, still does not print "found"

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Firestore DB? Can you print `querySnapshot.size`? Do you have specific security rules? Do you get an error?

Comment: i shared the screenshot of my database by editing the question, and querySnapshot.size prints 1.